# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hparam'

Tags: artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0, text-to-speech

I am trying to train a Text-to-Speech Model on google colab using the github repo: https://github.com/keithito/tacotron.git, which I cloned. On getting to the training, I encountered this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/tacotron/preprocess.py", line 5, in <module>
    from datasets import blizzard, ljspeech
  File "/content/tacotron/datasets/blizzard.py", line 5, in <module>
    from hparams import hparams
  File "/content/tacotron/hparams.py", line 3, in <module>
    from hparam import HParams
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

I found out 'tf.contrib' has been depreciated in Tensorflow2.x.

Here is the code for the hparam.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Default hyperparameters:
hparams = tf.contrib.training.HParam(
  # Comma-separated list of cleaners to run on text prior to training and eval. For non-English
  # text, you may want to use "basic_cleaners" or "transliteration_cleaners" See TRAINING_DATA.md.
  cleaners='english_cleaners',

  # Audio:
  num_mels=80,
  num_freq=1025,
  sample_rate=20000,
  frame_length_ms=50,
  frame_shift_ms=12.5,
  preemphasis=0.97,
  min_level_db=-100,
  ref_level_db=20,

  # Model:
  outputs_per_step=5,
  embed_depth=256,
  prenet_depths=[256, 128],
  encoder_depth=256,
  postnet_depth=256,
  attention_depth=256,
  decoder_depth=256,

  # Training:
  batch_size=32,
  adam_beta1=0.9,
  adam_beta2=0.999,
  initial_learning_rate=0.002,
  decay_learning_rate=True,
  use_cmudict=False,  # Use CMUDict during training to learn pronunciation of ARPAbet phonemes

  # Eval:
  max_iters=200,
  griffin_lim_iters=60,
  power=1.5,              # Power to raise magnitudes to prior to Griffin-Lim
)


def hparams_debug_string():
  values = hparams.values()
  hp = ['  %s: %s' % (name, values[name]) for name in sorted(values)]
  return 'Hyperparameters:\n' + '\n'.join(hp)
```

I also tried 'Automatically rewrite TF 1.x and compat.v1 API symbols' found on TensorFlow site but It was unable to upgrade the code.
Please Does someone have a solution to this?